# RabbitMQ consumer slow when there are un-ACKed messages outstanding

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

I have a .NET Core console application that reads message from RabbitMQ and saves the data to a database. It uses RabbitMQ.Client assembly 5.1.0 and sets up an EventingConsumer like this:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = _hostName,
    UserName = _userName,
    Password = _password,
    RequestedHeartbeat = 20,
    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
    NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
};

_connection = factory.CreateConnection();
_channel = _connection.CreateModel();
_channel.BasicQos(0, prefetchCount, false);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
consumer.Received += HandleMessage;
_consumerTag = _channel.BasicConsume(_queueName, false, consumer);
```

If I call `_channel.BasicAck` on the message inside my `HandleMessage` method, i.e. as soon as each message is received, the rate of messages delivered is ~1500/second. However, I want to wait to ACK the message until it's saved to the DB. If I do that the rate drops to 300-500/second.

Saving to the DB is done on a separate thread and is not a bottleneck. `HandleMessage` only stores the message in memory to be saved later on the other thread. I've tried experimenting with a various `prefetchCount` values from 100 to 100,000 and it doesn't seem to matter. If I profile the application I can see that the AMQP session thread ("WorkPool-Session#1:Connection(...)" spends most of its time waiting on a WaitHandle in `RabbitMQ.Client.ConsumerWorkService+WorkPool.Loop()`

What am I doing wrong? How can I consume messages faster without ACKing them immediately? (The server is RabbitMQ 3.7.7)

Answer (score 1):

The `prefetchCount` limits the amount of unacknowledged messages that will be delivered to your consumer. You can increase this value in order to receive more messages from the queue without acknowledging them.

However, since it seems the database persistence is the bottleneck, I expect the delivery rate to remain the same:
Lets say it takes you 2ms to complete the database insertion per message, which is 500 insertions / sec. Once you maxed out the amount of outstanding messages (the prefetch count), you are ACKing at a rate of 500 messages/sec, therefore you'll get new messages at this rate. The buffer size doesn't matter much for thus bottleneck.

To improve system throughput, you can have additional consumers, or improve the throughput against the database in some way or another (i.e. bulk inserts, schema improvements, sharding), etc., but RabbitMQ has no means of holding on to an infinite number of unacknowledged (in-flight) messages.

Comment: Database persistence is not a bottleneck. It's already done in bulk and can be done in ~0.2-0.3 ms/message when the MQ reader is reading fast enough. In any case, it's done on a separate thread and I can set a very high prefect limit (like 100K) that doesn't get hit for a long time, yet the rate of messages delivered still gets slowed down. This, in essence, is the strange behaviour I'm trying to understand: that if leave messages unACKed the rate of delivery is much lower even though the prefetch limit is not hit.

Comment: I even tried replacing the code that saves to the DB with a simple Thread.Sleep() with various values, but it doesn't make a difference to the RabbitMQ delivery rate. The rate is not constant, either: sometimes it jumps as high as 1800/sec, other times it drops to 150/sec.

Comment: @EM0 Did you ever make any progress on this issue?

Comment: @MNilson No. BTW, I have run into cases where the rate at which messages are read is a bottleneck, as M.A. Hanin says here, but I don't think that explains the situation where the prefetch limit is not hit yet, but fetching is much slower without auto-ack than with.

Comment: we are exactly facing the same challenge, but do not know how to solve it, good luck everyone